# Automating Script

Tags: ubuntu, shell, scripting

I am writing a shell script for ubuntu server that runs some commands and logs the file to syslog. I want to write an IF statement to where if the sudo apt-get update actually updates then it restarts the httpd server. How do I correctly syntax the If statement and then log the file to syslog? This is my rough draft of the .sh file, thanks in advance.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

sudo apt-get update

if [ update = true ]

then

< service httpd restart >

fi

sudo unzip randomnumber.zip -d /var/www/html

sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Comment: `apt-get` and centos usually do not go together...

Comment: updated to ubuntu server

Comment: Why would a blanket update trigger the service restart, wouldn't it make more sense if it happens when the package for that service is updated?

Comment: Remove the centos tag as well. What do you mean by it "actually updates"? Do you mean the process exits with a zero exit status (in which case you could just do `if sudo apt-get update ; then`), or do you mean that it actually updates any packages, or some specific ones relevant to the server? Don't you need an `upgrade` command in there too? Do you want to use the `-y` flag in your script, or will you run it interactively?

Comment: What I mean is if it upgrades then I want the httpd to restart, I want to run it sequentially without it being interactive.

Comment: Doesn't installing a new version of the httpd package invoke a post-install script that stops the old httpd process and starts the new one?